# How to apply HTTP 2.0 on the website

Tags: web, protocols, spdy

As everybody know the advantage of HTTP 2.0, I am wondering how to apply it on website to make website performance better. Is it install something on server or has any particular coding way to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dependent on the bowers and server. 
won't need to change any program to adopt HTTP 2.0.